# OneToOne Join in Foalts and Typeorm

Tags: typescript, typeorm, foalts

I have two entities that written in Foalts framework and they are using Typeorm.

This is `user.entity.ts` :

```
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  phone: string

  @OneToOne(() => UserProfile)
  @JoinColumn()
  userProfile: UserProfile

}
```

And second one is user profile:

```
@Entity()
export class UserProfile extends BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstname: string;

  @Column()
  surname: string

  @Column()
  email: string

  @Column()
  birthDate: number
}

export { DatabaseSession } from '@foal/typeorm';
```

My question is: How can i write a query in my controller to have an object like this in output:

```
{
    "id":41,
    "phone":"+18885555555",
    "userProfile" : {
      "id": 12,
      "firstname": "Pourya",
      "surname": "Daneshvar",
      "email": "example@example.me",
      "birthDate": 1613503707
    }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
@Get('/user/profile')
  async getUserProfile(ctx: Context) {
    const user = await ...
    ...
    return new HttpResponseOK(user)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add `Eager: true` option to the relation, described [here](https://typeorm.io/#/eager-and-lazy-relations):

```
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
    // ...
    @OneToOne(() => UserProfile, { eager: true } )
    @JoinColumn()
    userProfile: UserProfile;
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want UserProfile data to be retrieved every time you load User, you can add [relations](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md) option to `find` or `findOne`, e.g.

```
 const user = await User.findOne({ where: { id: userId } , relations: ["userProfile"] });
```